# Map a GraphQL field name to a different name in Java

Tags: graphql, spring-boot-3, java-21

I have a GraphQL type defined as such (I cannot change it):

```
type MyData {
   name: String
   package: Boolean
}
```

I am using Java 21 with Spring Boot 3.2.2. The word `package` is obviously reserved and cannot be used as a field name. How would I define my class to map the field name to something else?

```
public class MyData {
   String name;
   Boolean package; // Error here
}
```